# Get "eclipse-workspace" path in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

im trying to get the eclipse project folders in Java.

I tried the code below, but no luck.

```
String absolutePath = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println(absolutePath);
int last = absolutePath.length()-1;
absolutePath = absolutePath.substring(0, last)
return absolutePath;
```

output:

```
/home/itsdaniel/eclipse/
```

what I want:

```
/home/itsdaniel/eclipse-workspace
```

Comment: Append `-workspace`? I mean, the path is the path. Are you trying to set the path of the execution context?

Comment: I guess I should've specified a little bit more. Yes I could append -workspace but what if that folder is located somewhere else? the path wouldn't work.

Comment: Are you developing an eclipse plugin, or a plain jane java app which wants to return null or something similar normally, but returns the current workspace if run within eclipse as a normal java app?

Comment: Again: Are you trying to get the path of the execution context?

Comment: Note: If you want to do things to the contents of an Eclipse workspace you will need to write an Eclipse plug-in to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments before, it is not possible to access the workspace path inside eclipse from a normal Java application started by Eclipse itself.

If you want to access such information you have to write a simple eclipse plugin.

How ?

1. Download RCP eclipse, e.g: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-03/r/eclipse-ide-rcp-and-rap-developers
2. Unpack and start RCP eclipse
3. Create an example plugin, I think there is enough information at the web, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIweFZOf36E describes it very easy.
4. Inside the created Handler class fetch the workspace path location - e.g.  `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toString();`